# Delete text in file using bash script in CentOS

Tags: bash, shell, centos5

I'm a student from indonesia and I want to create an script that deletes few lines from a file containing the following text:

```
zone "irf.com" {
type master;
file "db.irf.com";
allow-update { none; };
};

zone "friedrice.com" {
type master;
file "db.friedrice.com";
allow-update { none; };
};

zone "you.com" {
type master;
file "db.you.com";
allow-update { none; };
};
```

If i want to delete this:

```
zone "friedrice.com" {
type master;
file "db.friedrice.com";
allow-update { none; };
};
```

In the terminal I can run:
`sh you.txt friedrice`

How is the syntax in shell programming??

All the text is in a file, let's say `you.txt`

I'm a newbie, so please help me

Comment: Please.. don't name your config or script files `*.txt`...

Comment: While you have received some good answers to your concrete question, they amount to using unstructured tools to manipulate structured data. You have zone data, not XML, but that's a detail; this is fundamentally the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i '/^zone "friedrice.com"/,/^}/d' you.txt
```

Comment: may i have your email?? so i have some problem in linux i can ask you,, thank you very much sir :)

Comment: @achmadirfan: If you have additional questions, please post them here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sed -i -E -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/zone "friedrice.com" {[^}]*};\n};//g;p;}' you.txt
```